# R-Hmisc impute by cluster result

Tags: r, replace, hmisc

I want to impute a variable x3 by the its mean corresponding to each cluster calculated considering other 2 variables X1 and X2. 
I know that you can pass a function to impute from Hmisc package, like "mean" and it does the work. So I would like to pass a function that does all the following.

I use to write the code to do so:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1=runif(1000,0,100),
                  x2=runif(1000,0,100),
                  x3=c(runif(900,0,100),rep(NA,100)))
```

I want to pass a function that does all of this:

```
clust<-kmeans(df1[,-grep('x3', colnames(df1))], 3)
df1$clust<-clust$cluster

library(plyr)
cc<-ddply(df1, 'clust',summarise, mean=mean(x3, na.rm=TRUE))

df2<-merge(df1,cc, by='clust')
df2$x3imputed2<-ifelse(is.na(df2$x3),df2$mean, df2$x3)
```

Is there a way to pass all this code as a function and use it in Hmisc? (I had a problem with ddply introducing x3 as a variable).

Something like the following:

```
ff<-function(i) {
clust<-kmeans(df1[,-grep(i, colnames(df1))], 3)
df1$clust<-clust$cluster
cc<-aggregate(df1[,i], by=list(clust=df1$clust), "mean", na.rm=TRUE)
df2<-merge(df1,cc, by='clust')
df2$x3imputed2<-ifelse(is.na(df2[, i]),df2$x, df2[,i])
}


f1$imputedx3<-with(df1, impute(x3,ff))
```

But I get an error:

> empty cluster: try a better set of initial centers

And when I replace it by x3 I don't get the same error.

Comment: Each value of x3 will be classified considering x2 and x1 depending on each cluster. So I want the meanof x3 that is the result of grouping x1 and x2 using kmeans.

Comment: @akrun please see edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
library(lazyeval)
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(dat, cname){
    #get the third argument i.e, 'cname'
    nm1 <- match.call()[[3]]
    #paste 'imputed' for renaming the new column later
    nm2 <- paste0(nm1, 'imputed')
    #create an numeric column index that will be removed in kmeans calc
    indx <- grep(cname, colnames(dat))
    #get the 'kmeans' of the columns other than the 'cname'
    clust <- kmeans(dat[,-indx],3)$cluster
    #group by 'clust' and create new column with 'mutate'
    dat %>%
       group_by(clust=clust) %>%
       mutate_(interp(~ifelse(is.na(v), mean(v, na.rm=TRUE), v),
                      v=as.name(cname))) %>% 
       #rename the column 
       setNames(., c(head(names(.),-1), nm2))     
   }

 f1(df1, 'x3')
```

Or you could pass it without quotes by using `v= lazy(cname)`

```
 f2 <- function(dat, cname){
   nm1 <- match.call()[[3]]
   nm2 <- paste0(nm1, 'imputed')
   indx <- grep(nm1, colnames(dat))
   clust <- kmeans(dat[,-indx],3)$cluster
   dat %>%
      group_by(clust=clust) %>%
      mutate_(interp(~ifelse(is.na(v), mean(v, na.rm=TRUE), v), 
      v= lazy(cname))) %>%
     setNames(., c(head(names(.),-1), nm2))  
   }

  f2(df1, x3)
```

Comment: can you please explain this part : match.call()[-(1:2)] ?

Comment: @GabyLP It is to get the third argument i.e `cname` or x3.  The first argument is 'f1', second 'df1', and third is 'x3'.

Comment: @nongkrong Thanks for the comments.  The `lazyeval` helped a lot.